If Statement returns false result-Arcade
When a point feature with Object ID 299 is selected, two other records from the same attribute table should be retrieved and displayed in a pop-up as a secondary table on the same Pop-up in ArcGIS Pro. I am employing the if statement Arcade Expression, but it returns false.
The following is a screenshot of the code and embedding of the expression into HTML for display in the pop-up. This is the code I am using.
if($feature.OBJECTID==299){
 return $feature.OBJECTID==297 && $feature.OBJECTID==300
}



Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour]

Is that all the code you're using?  It appears you're returning a True/False result (hence the false), and probably need a lot more Arcade code to produce your desired result

Are the points stacked, your screenshot is showing a selection of 3?

There are three data points on the map that are associated with a record in attribute table. When the user selects record #2, which has an Object ID of 299, the Arcade expression should retrieve the other two records, #1 and #3, which have Object IDs of 297 and 300, and display them as a second table in the pop-up window.
I hope this helps and it is clear.
I could create a subtype in the attribute table; however, I only have one case of this kind. Therefore, I believe it would be better to accomplish this with Arcade.

If the $feature.OBJECTID is 299 then it can not also be 297 and 300.  Perhaps look at the $layer featureset with a filter.

Answered on Esri Community
